# Streaming data into hbase 0.98.1 using flume 1.4 wiith a custom sink

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, flume, znodes

I am trying to load data into hbase using apache flume using a custom sink but I get this error:

```
ERROR async.HBaseClient: The znode for the -ROOT- region doesn't exist! 14/05/14 
17:12:08     ERROR lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start SinkRunner: { 
policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@923288b counterGroup:{ name:null 
counters:{} } } - Exception follows. org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Interrupted while waiting for Hbase Callbacks at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink.start(AsyncHBaseSink.java:379)
```

Note: my hbase run properly and I can create table, put data and get with a java client.

this my flume.conf:

```
# A single-node Flume configuration
# uses exec and tail and will write a file every 10K records or every 1 min
# Name the components on this agent
agent3.sources = source1
agent3.sinks = sink1
agent3.channels = channel1

# Describe/configure source1
agent3.sources.source1.type = exec
agent3.sources.source1.command = tail -f /tmp/testGenerate.csv

# Describe sink1
agent3.sinks.sink1.type =org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.AsyncHBaseSink
agent3.sinks.sink1.table = AdreamLumiHB
agent3.sinks.sink1.columnFamily =lumiCF
agent3.sinks.sink1.batchSize=5000

#agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer = com.hbase.log.util.SplittingSerializer
agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer =org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.SplittingSerializer
agent3.sinks.sink1.zookeeperQuorum=localhost
agent3.sinks.sink1.znodeParent=/hbase
#agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.SimpleAsyncHbaseEventSerializer
#agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex = 
#agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer.regexIgnoreCase = true
agent3.sinks.sink1.serializer.columns = id,nom,valeur,batiment,etage,piece


# Use a channel which buffers events to a file
# -- The component type name, needs to be FILE.
agent3.channels.channel1.type = FILE 
# checkpointDir ~/.flume/file-channel/checkpoint The directory where checkpoint file will be stored
# dataDirs ~/.flume/file-channel/data The directory where log files will be stored
# The maximum size of transaction supported by the channel
agent3.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000000 
# Amount of time (in millis) between checkpoints
agent3.channels.channel1.checkpointInterval 30000
# Max size (in bytes) of a single log file 
agent3.channels.channel1.maxFileSize = 2146435071
# Maximum capacity of the channel 
agent3.channels.channel1.capacity 10000000 
#keep-alive 3 Amount of time (in sec) to wait for a put operation
#write-timeout 3 Amount of time (in sec) to wait for a write operation

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
agent3.sources.source1.channels = channel1
agent3.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

this is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase-0.98.1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/alpha/hadoop_data/hbase-${user.name}</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
<value>0.0.0.0</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.master</name>

<value>localhost:60000</value>
<description>The  host and port that the HBase master runs at.</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
<value>60010</value>
</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>

<value>0.0.0.0</value>

</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/alpha/hadoop_data/hbase-data</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

this is hbase-env.sh

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1/lib
 export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/alpha/hadoop-1.2.1
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/alpha/hadoop-1.2.1/conf
export HBASE_LOG_DIR=/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1/logs
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/home/alpha/hbase-0.98.1/pids
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

this is custom sink

```
package org.apache.flume.sink.hbase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.flume.Context;
import org.apache.flume.Event;
import org.apache.flume.FlumeException;
import org.hbase.async.AtomicIncrementRequest;
import org.hbase.async.PutRequest;
import org.apache.flume.conf.ComponentConfiguration;

/**
 * A serializer for the AsyncHBaseSink, which splits the event body into
 * multiple columns and inserts them into a row whose key is available in
 * the headers
 *
 * Originally from https://blogs.apache.org/flume/entry/streaming_data_into_apache_hbase
 * 
 */
public class SplittingSerializer implements AsyncHbaseEventSerializer {
  private byte[] table;
  private byte[] colFam;
  private Event currentEvent;
  private byte[][] columnNames;
  private final List<PutRequest> puts = new ArrayList<PutRequest>();
  private final List<AtomicIncrementRequest> incs = new ArrayList<AtomicIncrementRequest>();
  private byte[] currentRowKey;
  private final byte[] eventCountCol = "eventCount".getBytes();
  private String delim;

  @Override
  public void initialize(byte[] table, byte[] cf) {
    this.table = table;
    this.colFam = cf;
  }

  @Override
  public void setEvent(Event event) {
    // Set the event and verify that the rowKey is not present
    this.currentEvent = event;
    String rowKeyStr = currentEvent.getHeaders().get("rowKey");
    if (rowKeyStr == null) {
     throw new FlumeException("No row key found in headers!");
    }
    currentRowKey = rowKeyStr.getBytes();
  }

  @Override
  public List<PutRequest> getActions() {
    // Split the event body and get the values for the columns
    String eventStr = new String(currentEvent.getBody());
    String[] cols = eventStr.split(",");
    //String[] cols = eventStr.split(regEx);
    //String[] cols = eventStr.split("\\s+");
    //String[] cols = eventStr.split("\\t");
   // String[] cols = eventStr.split(delim);
    puts.clear();
   /* String[] columnFamilyName;
    byte[] bCol;
    byte[] bFam;*/
    for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
      //Generate a PutRequest for each column.
     /* columnFamilyName = new String(columnNames[i]).split(":");
      bFam = columnFamilyName[0].getBytes();
      bCol = columnFamilyName[1].getBytes();

      if (i == 0) {
         currentRowKey = cols[i].getBytes();
      }*/
      PutRequest req = new PutRequest(table, currentRowKey, colFam,
              columnNames[i], cols[i].getBytes());
     /* PutRequest req = new PutRequest(table, currentRowKey, bFam,
              bCol, cols[i].getBytes());*/
      puts.add(req);
    }
    return puts;
  }

  @Override
  public List<AtomicIncrementRequest> getIncrements() {
    incs.clear();
    //Increment the number of events received
    incs.add(new AtomicIncrementRequest(table, "totalEvents".getBytes(), colFam, eventCountCol));
    return incs;
  }

  @Override
  public void cleanUp() {
    table = null;
    colFam = null;
    currentEvent = null;
    columnNames = null;
    currentRowKey = null;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(Context context) {
    //Get the column names from the configuration
    String cols = new String(context.getString("columns"));
    String[] names = cols.split(",");
    columnNames = new byte[names.length][];
    int i = 0;
    for(String name : names) {
      columnNames[i++] = name.getBytes();
    }
  //  delim = new String(context.getString("delimiter"));
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ComponentConfiguration conf) {
  }
}
```

Comment: please let me know where to place this customised code in flume libs. thanks.